# How to connect more than one arduino serial port together

Tags: serial

The idea is to connect more than 1 arduino slave to master as shown in schamatic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWtU2Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The problem is TX slave can not just combine to master RX.
It need to done some trick like tri-state buffer to make slave TX one at time.
Anyway, avr port can config as tristate buffer.
(Q1)Is there any software solution to done this?
Second If I connnect TX to RX for half-duplex communication (using 1 data line). How to make Rx stop listenning to its self while transmiting data?

Comment: Diodes and a resistor.

Comment: Two resistors--that's it! I just added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with two diodes and a resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYgEq7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You'll still have to implement some system to prevent collisions, but electrically that will be sound.

Comment: Does it have programing solution?

Comment: Tip magically turn the shave devices into open drain? No. Not unless you have the ability to reprogram the slaves and write your own implementation of software serial that emulates open drain.

Comment: Will something like Serial.end() and oinMode(x,INPUT) trick work?  or I need to write my own Serial library?

Comment: On the slave devices, yes, that would work - but would also disable serial reception. To prevent collisions you need the master to tell a slave it can send, which means reception needs to be working, or you need to implement some other form of signalling architecture (and that would most likely need more changes to your hardware). It's simplest to just add those diodes and a resistor and do it properly - or not use Serial at all and use a proper bus system like I2C.

Comment: Without the diodes or some form of direct control over when each slave can send a collision could be fatal to one or both of the slaves. It could cause a dead short circuit (one sends a 1 and the other a 0 at the same time) which could burn out the IO pins.

Comment: This approach you have keeps the Rx line always pulled to 5V except when a Tx line from a Slave goes LOW. I had to look it up to ensure that idle is in fact HIGH and not LOW, and yep, it is: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-communication/all#wiring-and-hardware -- see the diagram under "Hardware Implementation", and also: `A signal at the VCC level (3.3V, 5V, etc.) indicates either **an idle line**, a bit of value 1, or a stop bit`. So, yes, this solution would definitely work, although I think I prefer my 2-resistor solution I've posted here over this solution.

Comment: Sparkfun's explanations are excellent. I'm grateful they and Adafruit, in addition to Arduino of course, exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single-pole dual throw switch. a simple switch that can switch lines between multiple slaves.

Limitation: The salve will not be able to create a request unless the master has selected its corresponding lines.
Master has to actively ask for the data or send commands to the slaves. Slaves may not be able to initiate the communication (when not selected)

[image]

Comment: Appreciate for your participation but I prefer software solution first.

Answer (score 0):

For this scheme to work, you need to make sure that at most one slave
drives its TX at any given time. You will have to devise some protocol
by which the master addresses one slave, and then only that slave
responds. The problem is:

- both slaves must have their serial ports turned on in order to notice
  when they are addressed by the master
- an active serial port keeps its TX pin in a low impedance state,
  actively driving it HIGH when not transmitting data.

The best way out of this dilemma is to modify the hardware, as per
Majenko’s answer. If, for whatever reason, you cannot do that
modification, there may be a software-only solution, but only if the
underlying hardware allows you to turn off the serial transmitters of
the slaves, while keeping the serial receivers active.

The Arduino API dos not allow you to keep the serial transmitter active
while the receiver is disabled: the functions `Serial.begin()` and
`Serial.end()` control the transmitter and the receiver as a whole. You
may be able to do that by accessing the hardware at a lower-level. You
didn't state what kind of Arduino you are using. Assuming you have
something similar to an Uno, you can disable the transmitter with:

```cpp
UCSR0B &= ~_BV(TXEN0);
```

and enable it again with:

```cpp
UCSR0B |= _BV(TXEN0);
```

If you want to use the Arduino API for serial communication, you will
have to disable the transmitter right after `Serial.begin()`:

```cpp
const uint8_t TX_PIN = 1;

void setup() {
    pinMode(TX_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);  // valid when transmitter is off
    Serial.begin(9600);             // enable serial port
    UCSR0B &= ~_BV(TXEN0);          // disable transmitter
}
```

But beware that then it will be enabled for a sort time (no more than a
few microseconds), right before you disable it. This may cause a short
if one slave boots while the other is transmitting data.

One problem with this kind of software-only solution is that bugs do
happen, and with your circuit, a bug in the protocol handling can burn
your hardware. If you can manage to at least add some protective
resistors, as in Gabriel Staples’ answer, that should keep you safe.

Answer (score -1):

Update Nov. 2020: my answer below, though a bit insightful and with many correct statements, is wrong. My schematic below will indeed prevent the Arduinos from damaging each other, but it will not allow proper communication. [Majenko's answer here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/77592/7727) is right. Use his schematic, but read my answer below as well for additional insight and ideas.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

You can do it with 2 resistors, as shown below. That's it! Super simple!

### Electrical explanation:

The goal is simply to protect the two Tx pins from killing each other. Without the resistors one Slave might be writing output LOW while the other Slave is writing output HIGH, which is a **dead short**--damaging both devices. Simply putting a 1k resistor in series with each Tx pin like this prevents that dead short. Now, if one Tx pin is HIGH while the other is LOW, you get current flow from one into the other through a total of 2kOhms, which means the current will be only `I = V/R = 5V/2000 Ohms = 2.5mA`, which isn't a problem, as each pin can handle 40mA max and 20mA~30mA continuous safely. Also, a 1k resistor isn't much load, so you should still get good serial throughput even at fairly high baudrates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqelVr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

## The code:

The communication code will be done as normal with `Serial.print()` or `Serial.write()`, `Serial.read()`, etc. Nothing special about the code, except you should make an effort to keep the slaves from talking at the same time to prevent data corruption from slave to master. So, you should have Master *request* data from a Slave, and a Slave should only talk when it knows the other Slave is not talking (ex: it should only talk when spoken to). The Master coordinates the communication. In this way, this is like SPI: the Master is in charge and tells each Slave when to talk. Since both Slaves are always listening, just use an "ID" to indicate which slave is being spoken to. If a Slave doesn't see it's ID, it should ignore the message.

Ex:

Request a new temperature reading from Slave 1:

```
Serial.println("1:T");
```

Now, wait until you get the full response from Slave 1, then send out a request for...let's say, some current reading, from Slave 2:

```
Serial.println("2:C");
```

The exact communication codes are up to you--your imagination is the limit.

Again, both slaves see both messages, but they look at the number at the beginning and only reply if it's their number. Doing this technique, you could connect nearly infinite Slaves all on the same line, just adding a 1k resistor to each Slave's Tx line before the junction where they all connect back to the Master's Rx line.

Pretty cool. I never thought of doing this before until you asked the question. Good question.

Comment: You hardware setup can prvent damage but I wonder if one slave send no data (given High signal)  will the data get voltage divider effect that divide signal amplitude to half?

Comment: @Mlab: Indeed. A “silent” TX actively pulls the line HIGH. That's why you need the diodes.

Comment: @EdgarBonet  that why I seraching for solution to make A “silent” TX become high impedance. it should be possible by software some how.

Comment: I think my answer is wrong, and needs the diodes due to idle Tx being actively driven (low impedance) HIGH. I'll update my answer as soon as able. I measured the impedance of a HIGH Tx line at something like 26 Ohms early this morning.

Comment: 26 Ω is the expected resistance of an ATmega pin configured as OUTPUT. C.f. the datasheet section on [pin driver strength](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf#G3.2900717).